# What is the proper syntax to save this data to a database?

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, plugins, customization

I'm new to PHP, and I'm having trouble understanding how data is passed from forms to the database.

**My Form:**

```
<select name="parentgallery" id="parentgallery">
<option value="0" ><?php _e('Choose gallery', 'nggallery') ?></option>
<?php
    foreach($this->gallerylist as $gallery) {

        //special case : we check if a user has this cap, then we override the second cap check
        if ( !current_user_can( 'NextGEN Upload in all galleries' ) )
            if ( !nggAdmin::can_manage_this_gallery($gallery->author) )
                continue;

        $name = ( empty($gallery->title) ) ? $gallery->name : $gallery->title;
        echo '<option value="' . $gallery->gid . '" >' . $gallery->gid . ' - ' . $name . '</option>' . "\n";
    }                   ?>
</select>
```

This `select` I made is alongside a working `GalleryTitle` var that is passed to this function on the same page. So I'm guessing this is a good place to pass the data to the database :

```
if ($_POST['addgallery']){
    check_admin_referer('ngg_addgallery');

    if ( !nggGallery::current_user_can( 'NextGEN Add new gallery' ))
        wp_die(__('Cheatin&#8217; uh?'));

    $newgallery = esc_attr( $_POST['galleryname']);
    if ( !empty($newgallery) )
        nggAdmin::create_gallery($newgallery, $defaultpath);
}
```

The trouble with PHP ( as opposed to Rails which I'm used to ), is I can't see the lifeline of this data getting passed to the database. I can only guess what is getting passed and how it's being received.

**The Question:**

How can I post to the database my `parentgallery` value alongside the `galleryname` var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too specific to answer without knowing the underlying behavior of the create_gallery function of whatever existing software you're trying to modify.

The best I can tell you by looking at this, is the value of your parentgallery select on the form, looks like it should be available as $_POST['parentgallery'] in the receiving function. The rest of the implementation, is too dependent on the specifics of that existing application.